# three.js how to make double sided object

Tags: three.js, webgl

Blender export obj don't export double sided objects. How can I render objects in double sided mode. I tried this without succes:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load('models/test.obj');
    loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
        objects = event.content;
        objects.position.set(0,5,0);
        objects.scale.set(1.5,1.5,1.5);
        objects.mesh.doubleSided = true;
        scene.add(objects);
    });
```

Answer (score 78):

In your case, you add the following to your callback function:

```
objects.traverse( function( node ) {
    if( node.material ) {
        node.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    }
});
```

The `doubleSided` property of `Mesh` is deprecated. It was replaced with the `side` property of `Material`

Also, it is best to learn from three.js examples that work with the current version of the library.

three.js r.57

Answer (score 6):

### 2022

Future readers! Just add the `side` option to the material constructor:

```js
const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
  //           ^ this line here
});
```