# Faces missing after import

Tags: three.js

I have created this T-block by extracting a plane in Blender:

[image: Blender]

After that, I exported it using the [official Three.js Blender Exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) and imported it with the code below. But unfortunately, the faces are missing. I have read that it might be necessary to use `THREE.GeometryUtils.triangulateQuads()` but that didn't help. Any idea?

[image: Three.js]

```
loader.load "/scripts/blocks/T.js", (geometry, materials) =>
    THREE.GeometryUtils.triangulateQuads geometry

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry
        materials[0]
    )

    mesh.position.y = 500
    mesh.scale.set 50, 50, 50

    @get("scene").add mesh

    @render()
```

My blender is [here](http://nordformat.ch/T.js).

Comment: Could you send your blender file? What exporter did you use in blender? Have you tried to set your material as doublesided?

Comment: I have added my Blender file. I'm using the official Three.js exporter for Blender. Where can I set my material as doublesided? Thanks!

Comment: @WestLangley has already pointed out how to set the material as doublesided. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16028030/2940964 . Hope this helps

Comment: That works, thanks! If you write an answer, I would mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Blender is that some mesh operations needs normals recalculations.
Indeed, for instance when you mirror a mesh along the X axis , the resulting mirrored mesh will have inverted normals.

If you want to inspect your mesh in a deep way, you should try : [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)
This is an advanced mesh editoring tool. It has lot of filters and you can check and validate the face orientation of your modelled objects:

[image: Face orientation issue]

In the filters there is for instance :

- Filters -> Normals, Curvatures and Orientation -> Re-Orient all faces coherentely
- Filters -> Normals, Curvatures and Orientation -> Invert faces orientation

That way you would have a coherent mesh.

But if you don't want to do all that, you can just set the material of you model as double sided directly in your three.js scene.

@WestLangley has already pointed out how to set the material as doublesided. Here it is: [three.js how to make double sided object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16028030/2940964) .

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply recalculate the normals in Blender. The manual says, at http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Faces#Recalculate_Normals:

> Recalculate Normals

```
Mode: Edit mode
Hotkey: Ctrl-N
Menu: Mesh » Normals » Recalculate Outside
```

(note: there is also recalculate-inside but I edited that out here for clarity)

> These commands will recalculate the normals of selected faces so that they point outside (respectively inside) the volume that the face belongs to.

You can also enable viewing normals in the 3d view so can check if some are toward inside.

Two sided works too, and are needed of course when you actually need some face from both sides.