# THREE.js: Using OBJMTLLoader.load() to load a double-sided object

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I'm trying to load complex objects into three.js using the OBJMTLLoader from three.js, with double-sided materials. I've found the following solution, it works, but it's pretty old, and seems a little inefficient (if there's multiple levels of parent-child relationships for 100's of children).

[See this post for context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027131/three-js-how-to-make-double-sided-object)

Is there a flag or option, or generally more efficient method that I can use to set the .side property when using the .load() function for the objMTLLoader?

Comment: the question you mention has your answer. the geometry loader can only load one sided models; unless you duplicate the geometry.

Comment: The answer was from '13. I'm wondering if the loader has been updated at all, so that the side property can be set in a more efficient manner than traversing through the whole tree of objects (which could be very large), after the object has been loaded in.  I just figure that since the object loader has to build the tree in the first place, it might as well set the side property while it's at it.

Comment: then you can modify the loader yourself; it is open source.