# Double sided, obj model in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I set an obj model, to render double sided in threejs (r.84)?

Here is the obj loader code:

```
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );
  var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setPath('house3/');
  mtlLoader.load( 'House.mtl', function( materials ) {
      materials.preload();
      var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
      objLoader.setPath( 'house3/' );
      objLoader.load( 'House.obj', function ( object ) {
          scene.add( object );
      });
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [three.js how to make double sided object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027131/three-js-how-to-make-double-sided-object)

Comment: THREE.DoubleSide is your friend. In your case of OBJ loading, take a look at the similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027131/three-js-how-to-make-double-sided-object)

Comment: I tried that solution, but it did not work. Any suggestation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three js revision 84 does not have OBJMTLLoader:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8105

But the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027131/three-js-how-to-make-double-sided-object) solution is worked with a small modification:

```
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );
  var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.setPath('house3/');
  mtlLoader.load( 'House.mtl', function( materials ) {
      materials.preload();
      var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
      objLoader.setPath( 'house3/' );
      objLoader.load( 'House.obj', function ( object ) {
          object.traverse( function( node ) {
              if( node.material ) {
                  node.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
              }
          });
          scene.add( object );
      });
  });
```