# How to make inside color of cube visible in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to build a room with THREE.js starting from a cube. So far I have the following code:

```
function loadModelcube() {
    console.log("Inside the function");
    cube.traverse( function( node ) {
    if( node.material ) {
        node.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        }
    });
    scene.add( cube );
}

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,50,100);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff4444, wireframe: false}); 
cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

var managercube = new THREE.LoadingManager( loadModelcube );
```

With the code above, the cube is not visible as is expected. Also, I don't see the console logging being printed out as expected (ie due to the function `loadModelcube()` being called). Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [three.js how to make double sided object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027131/three-js-how-to-make-double-sided-object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the box geometry visible from the inside, you need to ensure that the [`side` field](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.side) of the `material` (ie the one assigned to your `cube` mesh) is set appropriately.

In your case, setting `material.side` to `THREE.BackSide` would achieve the desired result.

Applying the following changes should work for you:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,50,100);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff4444, wireframe: false}); 

/* Cause the material to be visible for inside and outside */
material.side = THREE.BackSide; 

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);
```

Alternatively, if you want the cube to be visible from the inside and outside, you could set `material.side` to `THREE.DoubleSide`.